# PHP exec / diff / No such file

Tags: php, exec, diff

I am using diff and sort to find the differences between 2 files. The following works perfectly from Linux prompt:

```
diff <(sort /real/path/yesterday.txt) <(sort /real/path/today.txt) > diff-today.txt
```

But I am failing to get the same command to run from PHP using exec():

```
exec("diff <\(sort /real/path/yesterday.txt\) <\(sort /real/path/today.txt\) > diff-today.txt");
```

I get the following error:

```
sh: (sort: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split that big command to small ones. Sort the files one by one and then do the diff. This code worked for me.

```
echo exec('sort /real/path/yesterday.txt > /real/path/yesterday_sorted.txt ; sort /real/path/today.txt > /real/path/today_sorted.txt ; diff /real/path/yesterday_sorted.txt /real/path/today_sorted.txt > diff-today.txt');
```

Comment: Thx. Sometimes it's easier just to split it up :-)